# How to remove all ocurrences of a substring containing unknown characters?

Tags: string, vb.net, replace, character

Typically, you would remove all substrings from a string using the following expression:

```vb
text.Replace(" uipath_custom_id=""587""","")
```

This gets rid of all substrings within the string, and doesn't throw an exception when there aren't any such substrings.

But what if I have unknown characters between the quotes? How can I achieve the same results when there are unknown characters?

This is the string I want to process. Sometimes it contains multiple " uipath_custom_id=""587""" substrings, and sometimes none.

```
outerhtml='<div class="_3_7SH _3DFk6 message-out" uipath_custom_id="567"><div class="Tkt2p"><div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[9:42 AM, 5/15/2019] sash: "><div class="_3zb-j ZhF0n"><span dir="ltr" class="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">Hello World!</span></div></div><div class="_2f-RV"><div class="_1DZAH" role="button"><span class="_3EFt_">9:42 AM</span><div class="_32uRw"><span data-icon="msg-time" class=""><svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 15" width="16" height="15"><path fill="#859479" d="M9.75 7.713H8.244V5.359a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H7.65a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2.947a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h.094l.003-.001.003.002h2a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-.094a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zm0-5.263h-3.5c-1.82 0-3.3 1.48-3.3 3.3v3.5c0 1.82 1.48 3.3 3.3 3.3h3.5c1.82 0 3.3-1.48 3.3-3.3v-3.5c0-1.82-1.48-3.3-3.3-3.3zm2 6.8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-3.5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-3.5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3.5a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3.5z"></path></svg></span></div></div></div></div><span></span></div>'
```

Comment: Define "unknown characters", what are they and why do they appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it must be said--regex is not the right tool for the job when attempting to parse or manipulate HTML.  HTML is not a "regular language", so regular expressions are not sufficiently powerful, if you will, to handle parsing them.  That being said, if what you are trying to do with the HTML is sufficiently simple, and the HTML being parsed is relatively consistent in its content and formatting, then sometimes regex is fine and a full-blown HTML parsing engine is just overkill.  If that's the case here, then you can do it with regex like this:

```
Dim outerHtml As String = "<div class=""_3_7SH _3DFk6 message-out"" uipath_custom_id=""567""><div class=""Tkt2p""><div class=""copyable-text"" data-pre-plain-text=""[9:42 AM, 5/15/2019] sash: ""><div class=""_3zb-j ZhF0n""><span dir=""ltr"" class=""selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text"">Hello World!</span></div></div><div class=""_2f-RV""><div class=""_1DZAH"" role=""button""><span class=""_3EFt_"">9:42 AM</span><div class=""_32uRw""><span data-icon=""msg-time"" class=""""><svg id=""Layer_1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""0 0 16 15"" width=""16"" height=""15""><path fill=""#859479"" d=""M9.75 7.713H8.244V5.359a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H7.65a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2.947a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h.094l.003-.001.003.002h2a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-.094a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zm0-5.263h-3.5c-1.82 0-3.3 1.48-3.3 3.3v3.5c0 1.82 1.48 3.3 3.3 3.3h3.5c1.82 0 3.3-1.48 3.3-3.3v-3.5c0-1.82-1.48-3.3-3.3-3.3zm2 6.8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-3.5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-3.5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3.5a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3.5z""></path></svg></span></div></div></div></div><span></span></div>"
Dim pattern As String = "\buipath_custom_id=""[^""]+""\b"
outerHtml = Regex.Replace(outerHtml, pattern, "")
```

Depending on your needs, you could make the pattern more strict.  For instance, you could limit the "unknown" text between the quotes to only get replaced if it's numeric, by using `\d` instead of `[^""]`.  Or, you could make it more lenient.  For instance, you could could make it allow spaces around the equal sign by adding `\s*` on either side of it, like this:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\buipath_custom_id\s*=\s*""\d+""\b"
```

The point is, regex is very flexible, so what rules you want to impose with it, or what variations you want to allow with it are up to you.  [Here's a handy quick-reference guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) for regex syntax in .NET.

Comment: Yes! Regex seems to work just fine in this case; and is definitely another tool to keep in mind for the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as you can see, it's quite powerful, so once you learn it, you'll start finding all sorts of places you can use it.  However, possibly even more useful than using it in code is the fact that most languages and developer tools support regex as well.  So, for instance, you can use regex in the find/replace feature in Visual Studio, or `grep` in the command line, etc.  So, it's worth the investment to familiarize yourself with it.